# How can I add javascript to a url javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I add javascript to my url in javascript here is the code:

```
<script> 
     showDialog('http://domain.com/users/profile.php?user_id= JAVA GOES HERE ');
</script>
```

I want to add javascript to the section after the = in the url so it would look something like this in javascript. Here is the code:

```
<script> 
     showDialog('http://domain.com/users/profile.php?user_id= javascript; ');
</script>
```

How can I add javascript to my url?

Comment: Umm, you can do that, but what would you actually expect that to do?

Comment: `'http://domain.com/users/profile.php?user_id=' + a_thing`?

Comment: That's a security hole.

Comment: You have the phrase "JAVA GOES HERE" in your URL, but it's important to note that Java and Javascript are completely unrelated languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do that!!

Malicious sites could have links or redirect to your site, so they will be able to run arbitrary JavaScript in your site!

That means that the malicious site will be able to make your client do arbitrary XMLHttpRequest to your pages, read/write your site's cookies, access sensitive information, etc...

But if you really want to run different javascript codes depending on a URL parameter, better use

```
http://domain.com/users/profile.php?jsfile=1
http://domain.com/users/profile.php?jsfile=2
```

where `myjsfile1.js` and `myjsfile2.js` are files stored in your server which contain your desired javascript.

And to run it,

```
var urlParams = location.search.substring(1).split('&');
for(var i = 0; i<urlParams.length; ++i) {
    var param = urlParams[i].split('=');
    if(param[0] === 'jsfile') {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.src = 'http://domain.com/users/scripts/myjsfile'+Number(param[1])+'.js';
        document.body.appendChild(s);
        break;
    }
}
```

This way malicious sites can only run YOUR JavaScript, which should be safer. But be aware that maybe they will run your script when you don't expect it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to break out of the string like so..

```
 <script>
         var uri = '123';

         showDialog('http://domain.com/users/profile.php?user_id='+uri+'');
 </script>
```

Also, 'Java' isn't Javascript. Just so you know.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
var uid="123";
var newURL = window.location.protocol + "//"  + window.location.host + "" + window.location.pathname;

var base_url=newURL?user_id=+uid;
```